# Why is this plugin pattern not return wjat I would expect?

Tags: jquery, amd

I'm trying to create a jQuery plugin using a modular pattern so I can use it with requirejs. I was expecting the code below to behave one way and it doesn't. I'm hoping that if someone can explain to me why it's not returning what I think it should I will help me understand. here's the code:

```
define(['jquery'], function($){

'use strict';

var pluginName = "myPluginName";

var Plugin = function( element, options ) {

    var _init = function() {
        console.log("hey");
    }

    return  {
        init: _init;
    }

}

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
            new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};});
```

Now with the above I was expecting that this would log "hey"

```
$('#elemId').myPluginName().init() //returns a jquery object
```

Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#elemId').myPluginName()` returns a jQuery object.

To execute init() you have to access the Plugin object in data attribute

```
$('#elemId').myPluginName().data('plugin_myPluginName')
```

this will return the object `init: () {}` that can be executed `$('#elemId').myPluginName().data('plugin_myPluginName').init()`

```js
var pluginName = "myPluginName";

var Plugin = function( element, options ) {

    var _init = function() {
        console.log("hey");
    }

    return  {
        init: _init
    }

}

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
            new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};

console.log($('body').myPluginName().data('plugin_myPluginName'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```